# Should we delete closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

We currently have more than 4000 questions that are closed, excluding being closed as duplicates.

Should we just delete most of these questions, since they don't technically add much value to our site?  I understand there are some questions that we could retain but I don't think all of these questions are actually useful to us.

Perhaps, we could just delete questions that have less than 200 views or something, to make sure we are not destroying questions that have a high public interest?

I am just dropping the discussion to the community and decide what is best for our site.

Relevant data query for tracking these questions:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61773/questions-that-are-closed-excluding-duplicates

Comment: Just to clarify: I am **not** suggesting deleting duplicate questions. Only those closed as off topic, NARQ and not constructive (and too localized, to some extent)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this is a good idea on a case by case basis--users with delete votes should use their best judgement in voting to delete when they see a closed question that is such (ie. off topic, localized, poor quality) that it would never be of interest to anyone.

However, I think that a specific campaign to find and delete such closed questions would be a waste of time that would be better spent cleaning up still open questions, fixing tags, approving edits, acting on flags, reviewing answers--and, of course, answering new questions.

If the site were to get to a point where we weren't busy with all these other tasks and the closed but not deleted questions were clogging search results, distracting from useful questions or answers, etc. then I could see such a campaign being a good use of time.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we should delete off-topic/NARQ after a specified waiting period to give the user a chance for rebuttal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we should delete off-topic/NARQ immediately.

Answer (score -5):

No, these questions should remain for eternity.